# It is possible to mute project name as presented in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

On the image below, i have a module `datastore` as part of the `IdeaProjects` project.

For display purposes, the name of the project is irrelevant for me. Is there a way i can chose to not display it?

[image]

Comment: What do you want to hide? `(~/IdeaProjects)` part?

Comment: Yes please, ~IdeaProjects is redundant for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder name can be hidden if you switch to the **Packages** view. It's not ideal as you might want to see other files as well, but I'm afraid it's the only way right now.

You are welcome to [submit a request to make it configurable](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).